# Get instance name from data source name

Tags: sql, c, sql-server, windows, odbc

I'm using [SQLDriverConnect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms715433%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to connect to database. In connection string I can specify ODBC pre-configured data source name (DSN), function resolves necessary attributes and all works fine. But after successful connection I need to get instance name to which I have connected or connection port (because there can be several instances of mssql running on server). How can I implement this?

Comment: Did you look at the OutConnectionString SQLDriverConnect returns? It might contain what you need.

Comment: SQLGetInfo + SQL_SERVER_NAME ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Run the following query on your connection:</strike>

```
select @@SERVERNAME
```

This will return the server and instance name

The preferred form is apparently to use [`SERVERPROPERY`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx):

```
SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')
```

which will return the server and instance name, and, unlike [`@@SERVERNAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx), correctly returns results if the server has been renamed.

Comment: I will consider this, but aren't there any way to do this without making any queries?